# Tier 2 visa question

Tags: united-kingdom, working-visas

I have spent 3 years in the UK on a Tier 2 visa from July 2009 to July 2012. However, I left the UK and since then I am living outside the UK.

Now I am getting an opportunity again to work in the UK and my employer is interested in offering me a permanent position. I have been told that I will be given a Tier 2 visa again, but for 2 years only. My question is, will the new Tier 2 visa be extendable? What steps can I take if I want to continue my job on a long-term basis?

Answer (score 1):

Which kind of tier 2 visa, have you been offered?

If T2 ICT, currently I think after April 2017 they only offer long-term visas, that I suppose is extendable from 1 to 3 then to 5 years. but ICT may not help you to settle down in the UK.

If T2 General, same rules may apply but that would help you to settle down, probably if u continue to stay in the UK and can apply for ILR after 5 years.

Please co-relate with UK gov site, this information is indicative only.

Comment: Ranvir: I have already spent 3 years on T2 General (2009--2012) but then I left UK for work. now I have learned that home office will issue me visa T2 General again but for a period of 2 years. now thetrouble will arise after 2 years when i will have spent all 5 years in total but not in one go. I will be asked to leave UK and my job as I may not qualify for ILR on account of my stay out side UK between (2013 to 2016). please advise If I am mistaking.

Comment: Sorry, I am not the best person to advise, maybe it's better to check with your company immigration team or just wait for anyone else to respond to your question.